# Can I include subjects with only one value (other values missing) in mixed anova?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, missing-data

I'm unsure whether it's OK to include subjects with only one value in mixed anova analysis. I know that mixed anova allows missing values across different time points, but the question is how much missing data is acceptable for inclusion in the analysis?
My subjects have data values as listed below (where x represents different values and rows represent different time points)
[image: anova]

All missing values are missing because of random reasons. So my question is, is it acceptable for me to include the samples that don't have a full set of values across different time points using a mixed ANOVA analysis? Because I don't have many samples to begin with, I believe including more data would be better?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot include subjects with missing data in standard RM-ANOVA (or ANOVA with both within and between effects). So it is not about being OK or not, it is technically not possible.

Only linear mixed models allow you to include participants which have missing values in some cells of the design.

Comment: Hi, sorry I do mean mixed anova that incorporates a linear mixed model I believe. I am using graphpad prism and they document that their analysis can incorporate missing values  see this : https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/statistics/stat_anova-approach-vs_-mixed-model.htm . So I suppose my question is is it acceptable for me to analyse this way (with subjects with only one value)?